# Search for a value in all column and all tables of a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to find the column name that contain the value "Commerciale", but i do not know the column name or the table so I need to search in the whole database. How can i do that with a query?

I'm using SQL SERVER

Comment: Use INFORMATION_SCHEMA to get all tables and their columns. Use dynamic SQL. Wait. Wait. Wait.

Comment: Please provide your DBMS product (SQL Server, Oracle, mySQL, etc.)  There are solutions to do what you want, but will differ depending on DBMS

Comment: Are you looking for a column with the name `Commerciale` or a column with a row with the value `'Commerciale'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for columns where the name is `Commerciale` then you can simply use the `sys` objects:

```sql
SELECT s.[name] AS SchemaName,
       t.[name] AS TableName,
       c.[name] AS ColumnName
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.[name] = N'Commerciale';
```

If, however, you need to search the contents of the values in the rows, you'll need to use dynamic SQL. This will return a dataset for **every** table in your database which has at least 1 string type column, and will return any rows where the value of one of those columns has the value `'Commerciale'`. If it needs to contain the value, change the `WHERE` to use a `LIKE` in it's clauses instead (note the query will be horrifically slow with that):

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = STUFF((SELECT @CRLF +
                         N'SELECT N' + QUOTENAME(s.[name],'''') + N' AS SchemaName,' + @CRLF +
                         N'       N' + QUOTENAME(t.[name],'''') + N' AS TableName,' + @CRLF +
                         N'       *' + @CRLF +
                         N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + @CRLF + 
                         N'WHERE ' +
                         STUFF((SELECT @CRLF +
                                       N'  AND ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N' = ''Commerciale'''
                                FROM sys.columns c
                                     JOIN sys.types ct ON c.system_type_id = ct.system_type_id
                                WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
                                  AND ct.[name] IN (N'char',N'varchar',N'nchar',N'nvarchar')
                                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,8,N'') + N';'
                  FROM sys.schemas s
                       JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,2,N'');

--PRINT @SQL; --YOu best friend

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

This won't tell you *what* column has the value, you'll need to use your own eyes to do that, but I wasn't entertaining writing a dynamic table dynamic pivot.

Answer (score 1):

you can use system tables :

```
SELECT 
    c.name ColumnName
 , t.name TableName
FROM sys.columns AS c
JOIN sys.tables AS t
ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name like '%Commerciale%'
```